# kendo ui ToDataSourceResult support mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, web, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

i Have Kendo ui Grid In My Project (client side) and in my grid FilterAble and Sortable and ... is true and set on serverSide operation

but my database is mongodb and now when in my client user set filter 
i got this error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in  MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Compare({document}{Name}.ToLower(), "test") is not supported.

because i use webapi i Create My own DataSourceRequest Class without inheritance 
when i want  convert my own class to DataSourceRequest with this method(for filterAble )

```
 if (model.Filter != null && model.Filter.Filters.Count > 0)
        {
            var filters = new FilterDescriptorCollection();

            foreach (var f in model.Filter.Filters)
            {
                FilterDescriptor filter = new FilterDescriptor()
                {
                    Member = f.Field,
                    Operator =(FilterOperator)f.Operator,
                    Value = f.Value
                };
                filters.Add(filter);
            }

            request.Filters = filters;
        }
```

this my repository

```
 var result = _context.Additives.AsQueryable().Select(a => new AdditiveList()
        {
            Id = a.Id.DbId,
            Name = a.Name,
            CurrentWeight = a.CurrentWeight,
            InitialWeight = a.InitialWeight
        }).ToDataSourceResult(model.ToDataSourceRequest());
```

now i have this question 
i was wrong for filter Creating ?
or 
kendo dont support mongo operation and  i must write this for myself?

tnks

Comment: What do you think about `Compare({document}{Name}.ToLower(), "test")`? May you put that block of code in your project include this part (`Compare({document}{Name}.ToLower(), "test")` in your question?

Comment: this block created by kendo ui (ToDataSourceResult) I Add Repository Code

Comment: Have you any `name` with `NULL` value in the `Additives`? Try fill all of the `name` field values with some data else null and test again. Do you see the error after apply these changes?

Comment: I dont Have any Null Value for name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem 
in my Filter class (model) i have one enum and my enum has wrong value 
i change my enum to this values

```
 public enum MyFilterOperator
{
    Lt,
    Lte,
    Eq,
    Neq,
    Gte,
    Gt,
    Startswith,
    Endswith,
    Contains,
    IsContainedIn,
    Notsubstringof,
    IsNull,
    IsNotNull,
    IsEmpty,
    IsNotEmpty
}
```

and now every things work correctly